# Get open file path from pfiles output

Tags: filesystems, solaris

We have detected performance issues in a Solaris 10 process and observed too much writes to descriptor 268 using `truss`.

We don't have `lsof` at hand, but here is an excerpt from `pfiles` output:

```
 [...]
 268: S_IFREG mode:0644 dev:321,11003 ino:13621 uid:101 gid:105 size:100014416
      O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE
 [...]
```

Is there a way to know the real file path from this information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *ino* value is the inode of the file on the filesystem, in your case  13621 so you could use `find`'s -inum option like so (where $filesystem_name is a filesystem on your machine:

```
find /$filesystem_name -inum 13621
```

Inodes are unique per filesystem, so if you have multiple filesystems you might want to check them individually.

There are some nice dtrace scripts on the web for finding activity on filesystems:

http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5075136

Comment: Is there a way to know which filesystem to search into from the pfiles info?

Comment: The dev:321,11003 will be the major/minor number of the filesystem.

Comment: ls -lL will show you major minor numbers. Do ls -lL on the underlying disks to discover yours.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find that info. Could you please provide a sample `ls -lL` output?

Answer (score 1):

The file path should appear just after the line you posted. If it isn't there, it is likely to have been removed earlier.

Comment: You're right the path was displayed for other files. Is the file being removed the only reason for not displaying the path? Why then is the reference still open?

Comment: If a process has an open file handle and the file has been rm'ed by somebody else then there would be no filename.

Comment: I guess that could be the case if rotating log files...

Comment: There are no other reasons I'm aware of for pfiles not to display the filename. A bogus log file rotation would be a likely cause indeed. As long as at least a process has the removed file open, its contents, despite being unreachable, will keep using more and more disk space. The only clean way to end that situation is to restart the process, or at least have it reopen the log file, if it implements that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly look for the open() call that resulted in filehandle 268 and see what params it was called with.

I'm not familiar with the particulars of Solaris's /proc filesystem, but /proc/fd/ under linux has a list of open filedescriptors and what they're opening; if Solaris has something similar, that might help.

Comment: After several tries we were lucky to catch the call when file was being rotated, but I would like to know a way to get the path when there's no open() captured.

Comment: The pathname used to open a file isn't recorded anywhere after that file has been deleted. You can still see its content by using this path: /proc/<pid>/path/<filedescriptor>.